# Open website in new tab

Tags: asp.net

How to open web link in new tab. If i specify Google
means on clicking the link, it opens in new new window and not in new tab. How to make the web link open in new tab?

[image]

I am using IE8 browser, i have set settings to open links from other programs in new tab but still it opens up in new window!!!

Comment: you have used asp.net does it mean you have problem in asp.net or windows os

Comment: In my ASP.Net website, i have used a HTML anchor tag to open a link in new tab!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior whether a page opens up in a new window or a new tab depends on the web browser. Actually there is **always** a new window opened but you can set your browser to open new windows in a new tab.

Comment: I am using IE8 browser, i have set settings to open links from other programs in new tab but still it opens up in new window!!! Please take a look at the screen shot present in the question

Comment: Try the option "Always open pop-ups in a new tab".

Answer (score 2):

in an HTML anchor you can only specify a link to be in the same or in a new window. if this 'new window' is either a new tab or a real new window is pure browser settings.